# Angular (Angular 4) RouterLinkActive for Menu and SubMenu configuration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

My app has a menu and a submenu. When they click on the menu, I need that menu item and the first submenu item to be "active".

```
-------------------------
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
-------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
-------------------------
```

For instance, if I select `A` then both `A` and `1` are "active". If I select `B` then both `B` and `1` are "active". Same for `C`.

**Routes**

```
const subMenuRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '0', component: ContentComponent }, 
  { path: '1', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '2', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '3', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '4', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '5', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '6', component: ContentComponent },
];

const menuRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'A', component: SubMenuComponent, children: subMenuRoutes }, 
  { path: 'B', component: SubMenuComponent, children: subMenuRoutes },
  { path: 'C', component: SubMenuComponent, children: subMenuRoutes },
];
```

**Menu Links**

```
links = [
  new Link('A', ['/A', '1']),
  new Link('B', ['/B', '1']),
  new Link('C', ['/C', '1']),
];
```

**SubMenu Links**

```
links = [
  new Link('1', ['1']),
  new Link('2', ['2']),
  new Link('3', ['3']),
  new Link('4', ['4']),
  new Link('5', ['5']),
  new Link('6', ['6']),
];
```

With this setup, clicking on `A` will go to `/A/1` and both `A` and `1` are "active". But when I click on the submenu, say `2`, then `A` is not "active" anymore because it matches against `/A/1` (which makes sense, that's what it's linked to).

Is there a way to specify that I want to match on just `A`?

https://embed.plnkr.co/BQKy67J2OfVskmwPbTDl

Comment: can you explain what is your expectation? if you can create a plunker

Comment: @Aravind I added a plunker. Not sure how to embed... If someone could please edit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your routing and in your definition of `Link`. You should define only the parent components in the links. Otherwise it only matches to `(A|B|C)/1`.

```
links = [
  new Link('A', ['/A']),
  new Link('B', ['/B']),
  new Link('C', ['/C']),
];
```

Then use `redirectTo` in your sub routes.

```
const subMenuRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '1' }
  { path: '0', component: ContentComponent }, 
  { path: '1', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '2', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '3', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '4', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '5', component: ContentComponent },
  { path: '6', component: ContentComponent },
];
```

Also you don't have to redirect to sub routes directly; redirect to parent, let it handle redirecting to sub routes. This way is more modular in my opinion.

```
const menuRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'A', component: SubMenuComponent, children: subMenuRoutes }, 
  { path: 'B', component: SubMenuComponent, children: subMenuRoutes },
  { path: 'C', component: SubMenuComponent, children: subMenuRoutes },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'A' }
];
```

Check the [edited plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/y7wmFr5ZCpHgVMQUXPjR?p=preview).

Comment: @christo8989 As a bonus, your `Link` class can be an `interface` since it doesn't have any behavior inside.